# Thin fails spawning workers when running on EventMachine

Tags: ruby, eventmachine, thin

I have a ruby web- / data-server application which is built on a Sinatra foundation. I'm adding EventMachine and em-websocket so that I can have async data transfer connections.

```
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

require 'yajl'
require 'json'
require 'em-websocket'
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thin'
require './Actors/DataProvider.rb'

my_host = '10.2.56.87'
my_web_port = '4004'
my_web_sock = '8008'

EventMachine.epoll  # choose kernel epoll over select for deterministic execution under load
EventMachine.run do

   class SinatraApp < Sinatra::Base

    configure do
      set :bind, '10.2.56.87'
      set :port, '4004'
    end

    encoder = Yajl::Encoder.new
    communicator = DataProvider.new( encoder )

    get '/' do
      redirect '/index-work.html'
    end

    before do
      content_type 'application/json'
    end

    post '/auth' do
    end

    post '/data/:id' do
      puts 'got d i '
    end
  end
  EventMachine::WebSocket.start( :host => my_host, :port => my_web_sock ) do | ws |
    ws.onopen do

    end
    ws.onmessage do

    end
    ws.onclose do

    end
  end
  begin
    SinatraApp.run!
  rescue => ex
    puts "#{ ex.class}: #{ ex.message }"
  end
end
```

The Thin server worked fine when just serving Sinatra, but now that I've added the EM foundation the following occurs:

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:192:in `block (2 levels) in start': undefined method `attach_server' for EventMachine:Module (NoMethodError)
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:191:in `each'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:191:in `block in start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/backends/prefork.rb:30:in `block (2 levels) in start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/backends/prefork.rb:23:in `block in start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker/worker.rb:52:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker/worker.rb:52:in `work'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker.rb:129:in `block (2 levels) in spawn_missing_workers'
from (eval):6:in `block in fork'
from (eval):6:in `fork'
from (eval):6:in `fork'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker.rb:126:in `block in spawn_missing_workers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker.rb:124:in `times'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker.rb:124:in `spawn_missing_workers'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/preforker-0.1.1/lib/preforker.rb:44:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/backends/prefork.rb:37:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/thin-2.0.0.pre/lib/thin/server.rb:187:in `start'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/thin.rb:13:in `run'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/sinatra-1.3.3/lib/sinatra/base.rb:1350:in `run!'
from /home/devel/ISF_Server/server-work.rb:122:in `block in <top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `call'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run_machine'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/eventmachine-1.0.0/lib/eventmachine.rb:187:in `run'
from /home/devel/ISF_Server/server-work.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:127:in `debug_load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:127:in `debug_program'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p286/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.17.beta14/bin/rdebug-ide:118:in `<top (required)>'
from -e:1:in `load'
from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I do notice that the Thin gem was recently updated, but EM has not been. That's my next point of inquiry. Somebody else posted that Thin should not be run from within EM.run block, but the example I am building from had it this way.

Comment: most likely your `EM` is out of date - `undefined method `attach_server' for EventMachine:Module`

Comment: That was my first thought. Everything is up-to-date, according to gem update. 1.0.0 released September 12th this year.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. I corresponded with Marc-Andre Cournoyer directly. He says, first, don't spawn This (through Sinatra) inside an EM.run block.

Secondly, the error is generated from Thin 2 (pre) which requires the EventMachine live Edition, or gem eventmachine-le.

Mo' bettah now. :D